# Add a Flag to an exposed filter result query in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, bookmarks

I have an exposed filter for one of my views. I would like users to be able to flag specific search results so they can return to them later. All using the flag API. I know flags are normally for nodes, but is there a work around so these flagged searches can be displayed among their normal node flags... and separately?

Big Thanks on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flag module doesn't provide anything like that unfortunately.

If you are using Drupal 6, maybe try something like this?
http://drupal.org/project/views_savedsearches

I haven't used it, but it seems to do what you are looking for.